# Unable to see the "Present Modally" option on the Storyboard Segue "kind" field:

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue, xcode8

I cant see the "Present Modally" option in my project but I can see the option in another project that I'm working off of (designcode.io)

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mspfD.jpg) of the difference in options

Comment: It says Modal in the screenshot. Have you tried hat?

Answer (score 2):

It's all a question of whether or not your Storyboard has Use Trait Variations checked.

[image]

- If yes, your segues are Adaptive and Present Modally is one of them. That is the situation in your *second* screen shot.
- If not, you have "old-style" segues and you see the old name, Modal. That is the situation in your *first* screen shot.

You'll notice that the "Deprecated" segues in your second screen shot, where Trait Variations *is* checked, are exactly the segues listed in your first screen shot, where it is *not* checked.